# Lucene search not working

Tags: c#, search, lucene, sitecore, sitecore6

I have a function which searches some articles in the Sitecore content items and give me the value. So far I have build up my indexes and it is showing in my IndexViewer. But the return of the function is 0. I looked up this link: http://sitecoregadgets.blogspot.com/2009/11/working-with-lucene-search-index-in_25.html for more information.

```
 protected IEnumerable<Item> ShowHomePageNews(int numOfArticles, string stringofCountries)
    {
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        Sitecore.Search.Index indx = SearchManager.GetIndex("newsArticles");
        using (IndexSearchContext searchContext = indx.CreateSearchContext())
        {
            var db = Sitecore.Context.Database;
            CombinedQuery query = new CombinedQuery();
            QueryBase catQuery = new FieldQuery("countries", stringofCountries); //FieldName, FieldValue.
            SearchHits results = searchContext.Search(catQuery); //Searching the content items by fields.
            SearchResultCollection result = results.FetchResults(0, numOfArticles);
            foreach (SearchResult i in result)
            {
                items = result
                              .Where(r => !r.Title.StartsWith("*"))
                              .Select(r => db.GetItem(new Sitecore.Data.ItemUri(r.Url).ToDataUri()))
                              .ToList();
                //Lucene.Net.Documents.Field url = i.Document.GetField("_url");
                //Sitecore.Data.ItemUri itemUri = new Sitecore.Data.ItemUri(url.StringValue());
                //Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(itemUri.ToDataUri());
                //items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
```

Over here the result is 0. What I am doing wrond here?

This is the snapshot of what I am seeing in my IndexViewer:

[image: IndexViewer]

**EDIT:**

I am passing a "NZ" in the 'catQuery' and I am getting the result back. Because in my index viewer I am seeing the Field Name = _name, which contains NZ in it. I got this part. However, I want my every field to be indexed. I am seeing only 3 fields in my IndexViewer: _url, _group & _name.

Comment: Can you specify the format/contents of values in the "countries" field, and the format/contents of the stringofCountries parameter?

Comment: Does the entire method return 0 results or `results.FetchResults(...)`?

Comment: Could you also add a few example rows of data that you are seeing in your index viewer?

Comment: Index Viewer will only show stored fields, not all tokenized fields. What sort of Sitecore field is "countries", and what value are you passing into stringofCountries? Are either or both intended to be multi-valued? Are you looking for an exact match on the field value? Or are you looking to pass in a list of countries and get results which contain ANY of the passed in values? Need these sort of details to understand what behavior you are expecting.

Comment: @techphoria414: countries is a multilist and I am passing the List<string> in stringofCountries.

Answer (score 1):

So your countries should be tokenized by the indexer. As a multilist, they will be tokenized by GUID. Searching for a single country by GUID with your code above should work. However, if you want to search for multiple countries, where any of the passed in countries can trigger a match, you need to structure your query differently.

```
CombinedQuery query = new CombinedQuery();

//apply other filters here to query if need be

//and country filter by creating a new clause (combinedquery) and "ORing" within it (QueryOccurance.Should)
CombinedQuery query3 = new  CombinedQuery();
//here you would actually iterate over your country list
query3.Add(new FieldQuery("countries", country1GUID), QueryOccurance.Should);
query3.Add(new FieldQuery("countries", country2GUID), QueryOccurance.Should);
query.Add(query3, QueryOccurance.Must);
```